# Tabulator processing ajax data before load

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I need help if it is possible to modify table data before load into table in [Tabulator library](http://tabulator.info/).
I need to convert decimal value of (8 poles)DIP switch to separate 8 bits and load it to table.
I have data in json format like this:

```
[
{"id":1, "name":"DIP1", "value":15},
{"id":2, "name":"DIP2", "value":75}
]
```

and I would like format data to this (for decimal value 15):

```
[{"id":1, "name":"DIP1", "sw1":0,"sw2":0,"sw3":0,"sw4":0,"sw5":1,"sw6":1,"sw7":1,"sw8":1,}]
```

to this table:

```
columns:[
        { title:'ID', field:'id', width:50 },
        { title:'DIP NAME', field:'name', headerFilter:'input', editor:'input', hozAlign:'center' },
        { title:' DIP SWITCHES', hozAlign:'center',
            columns:[               
                { title:'SW1', field:'sw1',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW2', field:'sw2',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW3', field:'sw3',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW4', field:'sw4',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW5', field:'sw5',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW6', field:'sw6',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW7', field:'sw7',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
                { title:'SW8', field:'sw8',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false },
            ],
        }
],
```

I know how to extract each bit in c:

```
 var sw1 = bitRead( value, 7 );
 var sw2 = bitRead( value, 6 );
 var sw3 = bitRead( value, 5 );
 var sw4 = bitRead( value, 4 );
 var sw5 = bitRead( value, 3 );
 var sw6 = bitRead( value, 2 );
 var sw7 = bitRead( value, 1 );
 var sw8 = bitRead( value, 0 );
```

but I dont know how to do this when data are loaded into table using ajax.

Can somebody help how to do it please?

I am newbie and I cant help myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread the switches to a separate bit values like that:

```js
// You may need to parse (JSON.parse()) if serialized
let data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "DIP1",
    "value": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "DIP2",
    "value": 75
  }
]

let transformed = data.map(({
  value,
  ...data
}, i) => {
  // toString(2) transforms a number to a binary string
  // PadStarts adds the zeros on left if neccessary
  // split converts the string to array of 8 bits
  let toBits = value.toString(2).padStart(8, "0").split("")
  // this will create an object of eight bits with according values
    .reduce((accum, bit, i) => {
      accum["sw" + (i + 1)] = Number(bit)
      return accum
    }, {})
  
  // spread operator will flatten the object
  return {
    id: i + 1,
    ...data,
    ...toBits,
  }
})

console.log(transformed)
```

Then, you should be able to use the content `transformed` as the table data like that (see http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data):

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  // ...other options
          ajaxResponse: function (url, params, response) {
          //url - the URL of the request
          //params - the parameters passed with the request
          //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.
          
          // `response` might be rather be `response.data` or such...
          let transformed = response.map(({ value, ...data }) => {
            let toBits = value
              .toString(2)
              .padStart(8, "0")
              .split("")
              .reduce((accum, bit, i) => {
                accum["sw" + (i + 1)] = Number(bit);
                return accum;
              }, {});

            return {
              ...data,
              ...toBits,
            };
          });
          return transformed;
        },
      });

      table.setData(<YOUR API URL>); // Change to your API endpoint
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for fast reply!Your code look great for me.My table setup do an ajax request from server on startup and take json data : {"id":1, "name":"DIP1", "value":15} to the table immediatelly, so I dont know where I have put your great code.Maybe I should make button "Load Data" somewhere on page and put your code there.Or maybe I am so stupid and dont know how to use built in routines in Tabulator library...

Comment: Hi, I've tried to add the code for the actual data fetching/displaying, but with no warranty – I have no experience with Tabulator (just took a quick look into the docs). I hope it will work, if you'd run into any troubles, try to paste error codes or such into comments, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hi, You are great!!! Its works fine.I did some minor modifications and all is OK.Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: One more question.Another device send data which does not contain item "id" inside json so I got message {"name":"DIP1", "value":15},Can you please modify your code to add item "id": + ascending number to begining each json data?some like this: {"id":1, "name":"DIP1", "value":15}.It is so difficult for me...

Comment: No problem. I updated the first snippet (notice the added the `i` argument in the map callback and later in the returned object as the value of `id` property.). This should do the job. If you want to put together data from multiple API call or want them to persist, it would be more complex and probably a topic for a separate question. If you find my answer helpful, you can reward me by upvoting. Cheers!

Comment: Hi,Thank you!It is working great!You find solution to this within a second, while I have been struggling with it for two or more months.My table can show all incoming data properly.I will study your code for future use, because some "thigs" inside are new for me( three dots, map, reduce .. almost all ).Thanks for your effort again!